# Stop manipulation inertia in Windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, gesture-recognition

I have an element that I can slide using Manipulation events and element translation. I also set ManipulationMode to the value All, so inertia is included.
My goal is to be able  to stop the inertia translation after I removed my finger from the screen while sliding.

I found this interesting article but I could not find what I'm looking for: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.input.gesturerecognizer.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2

I'm sorry if the question is not very accurate but I'm on phone. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I stop inertia in my app
I'll manipulate using [GestureRecognizer class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.input.gesturerecognizer.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2)

Here is a sample to do manipulations with gesture recognizer [Input: Gestures and manipulations with GestureRecognizer](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Manipulations-and-gestures-362b6b59)

The above sample code also works with WP8.1
Remove inertia supported modes from GestureSettings. Thats it, there will be no inertia while you manipulate. 
Remove these three..

```
Windows.UI.Input.GestureSettings.ManipulationTranslateInertia | 
Windows.UI.Input.GestureSettings.ManipulationRotateInertia |
Windows.UI.Input.GestureSettings.ManipulationScaleInertia
```